# Why $.post method doesn't work in IE?

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I've made a simple post call like this:

```
$.post("myPage.php", '', function(raw_data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    alert("in success");
});
```

But `alert` is never called in IE (7/8/9). In `myPage.php`, my content type is `text/html`. What's the problem with IE?

Comment: ...and it works in other browsers?

Comment: You should learn to find and interpret JS errors which show up in IE's JS console.

Comment: IE Console doesn't show any errors

Comment: If I post plain json string in php file it doesn't create problem, but when generating my own `content-type` and `content`, it causes the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was accessing data from another site and added cross-site configuration on that site. But Opera and IE didn't work with cross-site configuration. Using a proxy helped resolving the issue.

I know I didn't mention that in my question but may be my answer can help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.post("myPage.php", '', function(raw_data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert("in success");
    });

});
```

The webkit and gecko browser engines are (unfortunately) hell of a lot more forgiving than IE when it comes to letting you do stuff before the DOM is ready.

Read:

- http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I'm calling the method like this `<body onload="mymethod()">`